# How to move the camera in XNA only after few moments?

Tags: xna, c#, camera

I made the camera position 10 units from an object, but not behind it. I dont want the camera position behind the object right away when it rotates, I want that when I will rotate the object, the camera position will move slowly until it will be behind the object.

Answer (score 1):

Use a function that Interpolates between the two values such as [MathHelper.Lerp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.mathhelper.lerp.aspx) or [MathHelper.SmoothStep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.mathhelper.smoothstep.aspx) to smoothly rotate to the desired angle.

Comment: Are you looking from something along these lines? http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series2/Camera_delay.php

Comment: but the camera is always behind the plane isnt it?

Comment: Directly no. The faster the plane is turning the more the camera will be offset from directly behind the plane and when it stops turning the camera will gradually return to directly behind it.

Comment: I didnt understand the Quaternion, what exactly is it, and what .Identity means?

Comment: Identity for Vectors, Matrices, and Quaternions is the value that causes nothing to happen if you multiply it (similar to the integer 1 EX: 4 * 1 is still 4). I'm not going to go into what a Quaternion is mathematically other than it is a powerful way to store rotational data. The Vector3.Transform bit is rotating the vector around the origin by the amount specified by the Quaternion.

Comment: Actually in a bit during my lunch break I'll write a small Interpolating w/ Quaternions tutorial that will hopefully help get you started.

Comment: So the quaternion gets an angle?

Comment: This answer is correct, I've designed camera systems for multiple titles and lerping the camera over time is the way to go. I generally have the camera maintain a desired position, and a current position, and I lerp the camera from the current position to the desired position over time. All changes to the camera based on movement of the target or input generally affect the desired position, that way the camera is always smoothly moving in response to input. There are occasional cases where you will want an immediate snap, in which case you just snap to the desired position.

Comment: I didnt understand the tutorial that ClassicThunder gave me :http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series2/Camera_delay.php

can someone help me?